# android error implementing pager on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Im implementing a pager inside a fragment, but i get this error

> The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type
>   HowToUse_phone

on

> ```
>   mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
>             getSupportFragmentManager());
> ```

here the code,

```
package com.chocte.ks_documents;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; 

public class HowToUse_phone extends SherlockFragment{

private LinearLayout lLayoutFrgHow;

ViewPager mViewPager;
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_how_phone, container, false);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    //mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    //get the layou8t
    lLayoutFrgHow=(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_how_phone, container, false);
    return lLayoutFrgHow;

}   

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            return "a";

        case 1:
            //return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            return "b";
        case 2:
            //return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            return "c";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
     }
     }
```

I saw is some problems when importing fragment, but as you see in my code im android.support.v4.app...

what else is the problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `getSupportFragmentManager()` call `getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`. You're now trying to call a method from `SherlockActivity` but you're in `SherlockFragment`; that's why you need to get a ref first to `SherlockFragment` object ...

But above will fix only the compile error ... I am not sure if you have any other problems in your code. According to previous answer you didn't instantiate your fragment view at the proper time.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to fetch the View, before you have inflated the Layout.

Assuming R.layout.activity_how_phone contains the Id to the ViewPager your trying to fetch here:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

It should be something like this:

```
   mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


   lLayoutFrgHow=(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_how_phone, container, false);
   mViewPager = (ViewPager) lLayoutFrgHow.findViewById(R.id.pager);

   mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

   //get the layout

   return lLayoutFrgHow;
```

Besides that, why are you using a ViewPager within a Fragment? Usually its used wtihin an Activity, and it is hosting the Fragments.

And in addition your using 2 Different Kinds of Fragments. In your ViewPager you are using Fragments from support v4, and your Class is a SherlockFragment.

Comment: You can host very well ViewPager in fragments. The classic dual-pane model with swiping data on right side uses this model actually - have a fragment in right side with a ViewPager. That fragment is the single fragment in smartphones (or at least in portrait mode), while for tablets (or at least landscape modes) it is the right sided fragment.

Comment: Good to know that. Didnt say you cant do it, just couldnt think of a reason to to that. But your argument seems valid :)